# htaccess redirect and rewrite not redirecting to a URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am new to htaccess redirect and rewrite. I have converted the following url

`example.in/celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=1`

as

`example.in/celebrity/1`
by the follwing htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^celeb_id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^celeb_gallery\.php$ /celebrity/%1? [R=301]
```

for again getting the value of `celeb_id` i am adding the followig code in the htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^celebrity/([^-]+)$ /celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=$1  [L]
```

I uploaded the htaccess file. when the url `example.in/celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=1` is trigerred, it changes as `example.in/celebrity/1` in the address bar.

But the webpage shows an error `This Webpage has a direct loop` in Chrome and in firefox it shows `The page isn't redirecting properly`. why its not working...?

The sample working sample.php file contains following code only : its working without any css.

```
<?php
echo "This is an sample page<br>";
echo "Celeb id:".$_REQUEST["celeb_id"]; 
echo "<br>";
?>
```

the celeb_id is passing in celeb_gallery.php file, but it does not opening any style sheets i think. and the code is here:

```
<?php include('cpanel/common/dbconnect.php');?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<?php
$ncel = "SELECT * FROM celebrity WHERE cel_id = ".$_REQUEST['celeb_id']."";
$ncel_e = mysql_query($ncel);
$ncel_f = mysql_fetch_array($ncel_e)
?>
<title><?=$ncel_f['name']?> | Site Title</title>
<?php include('common/css_js.php'); ?>
</head>
```

The style Sheets are called in `<?php include('common/css_js.php'); ?>` and its not working i think.

Comment: hi mukii can you change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /celebrity/([^-]+)$ /celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=$1  [L]`

Comment: its showing internal server error @nu1_ww

Comment: can you try this ? `Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^celeb_id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^celeb_gallery\.php$ /celebrity/%1? [L]`

Comment: the webpage shows `The requested URL /example/celebrity/1 was not found on this server.`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect calls to `example.in/celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=1` to `example.in/celebrity/1` you just need :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^celeb_id=([\d]+)$
RewriteRule ^celeb_gallery\.php$ /celebrity/%1 [L, R=301]
```

But if you want call to URL like `example.in/celebrity/1` to be process like call to `example.in/celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=1`

So you need :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^celebrity/([\d]+)$ /celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=$1 [L]
```

The [L] flag will make the htaccess stop processing other rules if the rule is matched

Comment: it changes `example.in/celeb_gallery.php?celeb_id=1` into `example.in/celebrity/1` but not showing any styles in the webpage. the url also not changing for `celeb_id=2,3,4etc`. url change works only for `celeb_id = 1`.

Comment: If your CSS file is reffered as by relative path take in consideration that from the server point of view the current folder is `example.in/celebrity/`

Comment: how to execute the css file...?